# Cant unpause in godot

Tags: godot, pause

I am making a game in godot. But I can't unpause after pausing. I used Input Map to create two keyboard shortcuts(one to pause and other to un-pause) and auto-loaded the script. This is the code:

```
extends Node


var players_coin = 0

func _ready():
    PAUSE_MODE_PROCESS

func _input(event):

    if Input.is_action_pressed("pause"):
        get_tree().paused = true

    if Input.is_action_pressed("unpause"):
        get_tree().paused = false
```

I am bad at stack overflow, but this should work.

I am using "Godot 3.2.2.stable" and any help would be great.

Comment: You forgot to set the Node's pause_mode on `_ready()` function:  `pause_mode = PAUSE_MODE_PROCESS`. See https://docs.godotengine.org/pt_BR/stable/tutorials/misc/pausing_games.html

Comment: @beroso I think you should post that as an answer. Perhaps along side a short explanation of what `pause_mode` is.

Answer (score 4):

Just **replace** your ready function with following:

```
func _ready():
       pause_mode = Node.PAUSE_MODE_PROCESS
```

Or
you can do the same thing in Node **under Inspector Tab**.

[here is the offical documentation link](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/misc/pausing_games.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is when you pause the tree, even the input process also stops.

FIX:
don't make it an auto-load script, attach it to a node and set its pause mode to process.

```
func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("pause"):
        get_tree().paused = true

    if Input.is_action_pressed("unpause"):
        get_tree().paused = false
```

I hope it will fix the issue. if not [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/misc/pausing_games.html) is godot's documentation on this

Comment: Hey, I just want to expand a bit on auto loads. They are plain nodes but on start godot will add them to the scene tree under the root before the main scene. Old versions of godot you would actually use `get_tree().get_node(“/root/autoloadname”)` and you can still do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple fix. The node that the script is attached to must have the process mode set to Disabled in godot 4.x but in 3.x it must be set to Process.
You can change the setting by selecting the node, scrolling to the bottom in the Inspector under the Node dropdown there should be a dropdown selection that either says Mode or Process Mode.

But if you are using an autoload you shouldn't have to do any of that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).